# CSS: Animating text from left to right on hover [fiddle provided]

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, transition

I'm having a problem of animating text from left to right. As far as I'm concerned there's no way out without some hack.

This is my nav on initial load.

[image]

Hovering an element reveals text for the icon

[image]

It would be awesome to have text from left  =>  right.

Current

*CSS*

```
.menu-item { /* hide and position tooltip */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s ease-in 600ms, opacity 600ms;
}

.menu-item-hover:hover .menu-item {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0s ease-in 600ms, opacity 600ms;
}
```

*HTML (handlebars)*

```
<div class="menu-item-hover">
     <i class="icon-my-menu my-menu"></i>
         <span>
              <span class="menu-item">
                   {{i18n-t 'General.myMenu'}}
              </span>
         </span>
</div>
```

Link to fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kristjanrei/kLd7obvg/

And the way text should animate

http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/SNycF/

Comment: it will be much easier to help you with a fiddle..

Comment: @LiranBo well ok. provided.

Comment: What do you mean by left=>right? text-align? As far as i know you can't animate text-align, but you could make the menu-item `position: absolute` and animate the `right` property to 0 to push the element to the far right of the container

Comment: @MattiaNocerino I basically need this . http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/SNycF/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There we go

http://jsfiddle.net/kLd7obvg/7/

I just used the `:after` pseudo element, make it absolute, cover it's parent a use a transition for its width

```
.menu-item { /* hide and position tooltip */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s ease-in 600ms, opacity 600ms;
    position: relative;
}

.menu-item:after{
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: width 600ms;
}

.menu-item-hover:hover .menu-item {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0s ease-in 600ms, opacity 600ms;
}

.menu-item-hover:hover .menu-item:after{
    width: 0;   
}
```

Comment: Wow thats decent. Thumbs up !

Comment: Thank you sir! But you have to thank the fiddle that you posted before, because it gave me the idea ahah!

Comment: I tried to implement my own solution based on that. It totally messed up for me. =)

Answer (score 2):

To have to text from left to right, just put it as absolute position and change `left` value

```css
.menu-item { /* hide and position tooltip */
    opacity: 0;
    left:-50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    transition: all 600ms;
}

.menu-item-hover:hover .menu-item {
    opacity: 1;
    position:absolute;
    top:8px;
    left:40px;
    transition: all 600ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-item-hover">
    icon
    <span>
        <span class="menu-item">
          my-menu
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kLd7obvg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <div class="menu-item-hover">
        icon    
    </div>                     

.menu-item-hover:hover:before {              
    opacity: 1;               
    Content:"my-menu";              
    transition: opacity 0s ease-in 600ms, opacity 600ms;          
}
```

Comment: I need i18n support.  {{i18n-t 'General.myMenu'}}